# SQLMap succesul inject query browsing

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, inject, sqlmap

i was wondering if there is a way to browse an SQL query SQLMap was using at the moment of injection so that I could paste this query into my browser and watch it work itself, without automated tools. Example:
I use the `sqlmap -u vulnerableparameters.com/php?id=5 --dbs` command and it returns the avaliable databases. How do i find out the query SQLMap used to access this data? Thanks in advance, I will keep researching.

Comment: If the injection is successful you can see the query in the description ( 'Payload' ) , when sqlmap finish .  
If you want to see all the injections it tries while the program is running , you have to increase verbosity to 3 - 5 , ie : `sqlmap -u target -v 3` .  
[Here](https://www.exploit-db.com/papers/13045/) you will find a good tutorial on how to exploit sql inj manually .  
Dont be evil ..

Answer (score 1):

While running sqlmap, you can listen to the outgoing traffic with wireshark on the backplane. You can see sqlmap traffic sent by the SQLMap program via Wireshark.

Or you can use tcpdump

```
sudo tcpdump -s0 -Xnnpi wlan -w /var/tmp/sqlmapOutput.pcap port 80
```

logs here: /var/tmp/sqlmapOutput.pcap

Or you can use sqlmap advanced verbose mode

```
sqlmap -u  vulnsite.com/index.php?id=2 -v 4 --dbs
```

-v VERBOSE            Verbosity level: 0-6 (default 1)

[sqlmap usage](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)

or you can use Bitnami Elk.

[Bitnami ELK installation](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/elk/)